# How I do get a python script that I run on a .cvs file locally, to work on MS SQL table?

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a python script that I used to run locally on a .csv file. How ever I want to run this on a table that has the same data in a SQL Server.

How do I approach this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hiyaqzm1uu8gld/Code.txt

Comment: Check out `sqlite3`. http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Is there a solution for MS SQL?

Comment: we're going to need to see some code to know how to help you with this.  Flat files and network connected databases could not be more different; there's no one size fits all approach for moving from one to the other.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hiyaqzm1uu8gld/Code.txt

Comment: @MannarKaryampudi basically your `writerows` will be replaced with bulk insert operation using mssql driver.

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely need to rewrite the code and use python MSSQL driver: [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) or [pymssql](https://code.google.com/p/pymssql).

Also, take a look at [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) sql toolkit and object relational mapper. It can help you to build an abstraction layer so that it would be easier for you to switch between different database backends in the future.

Hope that helps.